# Django queryset not updating on live server unless the server is restarted, but updates on local

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using Django version 3.2

This queryset updates on local and on live:

```
variable1 = serialize('json', Calls.objects.order_by('-time_pulled','-time')[:15].using('myDatabase'))
```

These two querysets only update on live after a server restart and then never refresh:

```
variable2 = Calls.objects.filter(local_date = current_local_date).using('myDatabase').count()
variable3 = serialize('json', Calls.objects.all().filter(local_date=current_local_date).using('myDatabase'))
```

I did read in the Django docs that .count() does not return a new queryset, but .filter() is supposed to.  I tried to use

```
Calls.refresh_from_db
```

but this doesn't refresh the queryset either.  I also tried calling

```
Calls.objects.all()[:15].using('myDatabase')
```

at the beginning of the view function to see if it would fetch a new queryset, but don't see the results in the latter calls. Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

###########EDIT - Added context#############
At the top of views.py I defined these variables:

```
utc_now = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.utcnow())
cst_now = utc_now.astimezone(pytz.timezone("America/Chicago"))

current_local_date = cst_now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Then I defined the first view:

```
def myFirstView(request):
    variable2 = Calls.objects.filter(local_date = current_local_date).using('myDatabase').count()
    variable3 = serialize('json', Calls.objects.all().filter(local_date=current_local_date).using('myDatabase'))
    context = {'variable2':variable2, 'variable3':variable3}
    return render(request, 'myReport.html', context)
```

These two do not refresh unless the server is restarted.
Then I defined this view:

```
def view2(request):
   variable1 = Calls.objects.all().order_by('-time_pulled', 'time')[:15].using('myDatabase')
   context = {'variable1':variable1}
   return render(request, 'myOtherReport.html', context)
```

This does refresh without having to restart the server.

Comment: Can you share where you defined those variables? Maybe share the whole context on where it is defined, and where it is used

Comment: Have you defined these variables on the class and not in a method?

Comment: I've added some context.  This is the basic structure.  These are the only places that these variables are defined.  There isn't any difference (that I can see) between how they are defined (the one that updates and the two that don't).

Comment: I see the difference.  Those two rely on the current_local_date variable.  I don't know why it's breaking as I've checked the variable value and it is consistent after declaration and in the view definition.  Thanks for the questions, they helped me look at it with fresh eyes.

Comment: It's because it's declared outside of the view function at the top of the views.py file and never gets reset after the file is initially loaded.  It is working as intended, i.e. the data never refreshes because the date variable is still set to the day the server was restarted.  I feel moronic.  lol